# What are the Win32APIs corresponding to the "Parent" and "Owner" Window values displayed by MS Spy++?

Tags: winapi

I'd like to obtain the same values via code. However I'd like to obtain the top-most or root windows in the hierarchy

I seem to have got the Root Parent with

```
HWND rootWinHandle = GetAncestor(activatedWinHandle, GA_PARENT);
```

However I can't get the owner window correctly. Tried

```
HWND rootOwnerWinHandle = GetAncestor(activatedWinHandle, GA_ROOTOWNER);
```

For a particular modeless dialog, Spy++ returns the Main Exe window whereas the above line returns the input i.e. activatedWinHandle. Am I looking at the wrong api ?
*I'd like to obtain this without MFC if possible... coz nothing else in my project requires it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the GW_OWNER flag for [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx).

The [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510.aspx) documentation states:

> If the window is a child window, the return value is a handle to the parent window. If the window is a top-level window, the return value is a handle to the owner window.

Comment: Yeah weird winapi. In the end, Parent => GetParent(hWnd) and Owner => GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER) is what worked. GetAncestor with all its flags doesn't return the same values for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Try GetParent(). I believe this will return the owner window of a window without the WS_CHILD style, and the parent window of a window with WS_CHILD.

Answer (score 1):

Only bit of insight i can add it from Raymond Chen:

> Remember that owner and parent are two
>   different things.
>
> Modal dialogs disable their OWNERs.
>   All top-level windows have the desktop
>   as their PARENT.

From: [What's so special about the desktop window?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Special demo (+src):

http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/parentowner.zip

screenshot: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/parentowner.png

kero